# read and write i2c in other existing driver in Linux

Tags: linux, driver, i2c

I want to modify a existing device driver to make it capable to read and write via i2c. Is it possible and how can I achive that?

Lots of posts are about how to write a standalone i2c driver (with init / probe). I guess there should be a simple way to read and write just like gpio does (with gpio_request)..

Comment: Find some existing driver that does this already and learn from that?

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question myself. Finally, I add all I2C driver code in the existing driver. The first time I know that any Linux driver module can contain more than one drivers in it (each with probe). Data is shared with module-scope global variables. (Is there any better approaches?)